# Adding Entry in ListView via Selection Mode

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-listview, selection

I have a listview containing movies. The list is declared in strings.xml. The user can add movies to this listview, can edit the entries and can delete the entries.

I am implementing a new "Insert" method which allows the user to highlight (ie, use the fire arrows, use the mouse's trackball) each entry, and insert a new movie right below the selected entry. My problem is that I am getting an arrayindexoutofbounds error in my code when I setResult from the Insert Activity:

One of my OnActivityResult cases:

```
  case INSERT_MOVIE:
            Lab8_082588FetchDetails insertMovie = new Lab8_082588FetchDetails();
            ListView list = getListView();
            list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            NumberFormat formatterInsert = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");

            insertMovie.setTitle(data
                    .getStringExtra(Lab8_082588Insert.TITLE_STRING));
            insertMovie.setGross("$"
                    + formatterInsert.format(Double.parseDouble(data
                            .getStringExtra(Lab8_082588Insert.GROSS_STRING))));
            insertMovie.setDate(data
                    .getStringExtra(Lab8_082588Insert.DATE_STRING));
            results.add(insertMovie);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My OnOptionsItemSelected:

```
      @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection using item.getItemId()
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.add:
        add();
        break;
    case R.id.insert:
        insert(item);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void insert(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    Intent insertData = new Intent(Lab8_082588.this,
            Lab8_082588Insert.class);
    insertData.putExtra(Lab8_082588.CURRENT_ROW, info.position); //nullPointerException
    startActivityForResult(insertData, Lab8_082588.INSERT_MOVIE);
}
```

My Insert Class:

```
    public class Lab8_082588Insert extends Activity {

public static final String TITLE_STRING = "TITLE_STRING";
public static final String GROSS_STRING = "GROSS_STRING";
public static final String DATE_STRING = "DATE_STRING";
public static final String PASSED_ROW = "PASSED_ROW";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addeditinsert);
    Intent rowNumber = getIntent();
    results.add(data.getIntExtra(Lab8_082588Insert.PASSED_ROW, 0) + 1, insertMovie);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu3, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection using item.getItemId()
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.insert2:
        next();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void next() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    EditText movieTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    EditText movieGross = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGross);
    EditText movieDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);

    String title = movieTitle.getText().toString();
    String gross = movieGross.getText().toString();
    String date = movieDate.getText().toString();

    if ((title.length() > 0) && (gross.length() > 0)
            && (date.length() == 4)) {

        Intent data = getIntent();
        int rowNumber = getIntent().getIntExtra(Lab8_082588.CURRENT_ROW, 0);
        data.putExtra(Lab8_082588Insert.TITLE_STRING, title);
        data.putExtra(Lab8_082588Insert.GROSS_STRING, gross);
        data.putExtra(Lab8_082588Insert.DATE_STRING, date);
        data.putExtra(Lab8_082588Insert.PASSED_ROW, rowNumber);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help a lot to know on which line exactly do you get the exception.

Comment: This one  results.add(list.getCheckedItemPosition(), insertMovie);

Comment: Didi you tried to see what is the value of `list.getCheckedItemPosition()` is and if it didn't returned `-1` meaning no selection?

Comment: I tried doing Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),list.getCheckedItemPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); but that line causes a resource notfound error: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffff

Comment: Use `Log.e("FIND ME", String.valueOf(list.getCheckedItemPosition()));` and then search the `Logcat` to see what you get. Or use the `Toast` like you did but add a `"" + ` before `list.getCheckedItemPosition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your code but why did you used the retrun of the `getCheckedItemPosition()` method as the newly inserted item's index?

If you just want to insert them *after* the row that was selected by the user then simple pass the position of the item that the user clicked(to the `insertData`, I saw in your previous question that you know how to do this) and pass this to the activity that would gather the data for the insert. In the insert activity, then along the user inserted data, return the position of the row(increment it with one so you can insert at the next position) and used that as the index in the list addition in `onActivityResult`.

You didn't quite understand what I said. In the `insert` method:

```
private void insert(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    Intent insertData = new Intent(Lab8_082588.this,
            Lab8_082588Insert.class);
    insertData.put("CURRENT_ROW", info.position);// there is no need for extra data, you're going to insert it anyway
    startActivityForResult(insertData, Lab8_082588.INSERT_MOVIE);
}
```

Then in the insert activity simply get that row number and add it to the intent when you return the result:

```
//
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.addeditinsert);
rowNumber = getIntent().getExtra("CURRENT_ROW");
```

and then pass it to the finish `Intent`:

```
    hobby.putExtra(TITLE_STRING, title);
    hobby.putExtra(GROSS_STRING, gross);
    hobby.putExtra(DATE_STRING, date);
    hobby.putExtra("PASSED_ROW", rowNumber);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, hobby);
    finish();
```

In the `onActivityResult`:

```
results.add(data.getIntExtra("PASSED_ROW") + 1, insertMovie);
```

Comment: Oh I see, where you're getting at. I changed my code a bit. However, I don't know how to access the index in the Insert activity class *Code:Updated

Comment: rowNumber = getIntent().getExtra("CURRENT_ROW"); doesn;t seem to work. I changed it to rowNumber = getIntent().getIntExtra("CURRENT_ROW",0); because what's being passed is an Integer. Also, hobby.putExtra("PASSED_ROW", rowNumber); also gives an error. I will update my code

Comment: @Erasmus I'm writting this from memory I don't recall the exact methods. What is the error at the `hobby` line? You should have a `int` field in the insert activity `rowNumber` which you'll initialize from the intent and then at the end pout it in the final intent that gets sent back.

Comment: rowNumber cannot be resolved to a variable it says. Also as you can see, I have made some changes on your rowNumber = getIntent().getExtra("CURRENT_ROW"); It says The method getExtra(String) is undefined for the type Intent. I changed it to rowNumber.getIntExtra(Lab8_082588.CURRENT_ROW, 0); and it has no errors

Comment: @Erasmus I hope that you don't declare `int rowNumber = getIntent().getIntExtra...` in the `onCreate` method and expect to use `rowNumber` in the `next()` method. Make it a field in the insert class.

Comment: Indeed it works, no syntax errors, however, the line insertData.putExtra(Lab8_082588.CURRENT_ROW, info.position); in the Insert function causes a nullPointerException error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15532/discussion-between-erasmus-and-luksprog)